# MoreEvents Module - Templates

Tags: module

it's good to see the answers from Brad on issues with MoreEvents. I have been trying to work with the module but wondered if my installation was ok or not.

Can anyone tell me if the module was supposed to install some templates only I cannot find any within the control panel?

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Just by the way, I'm the one who supplied the fixes.

No templates are installed, but if you following the documentation (http://moresoda.co.uk/docs/moreevents/sections/templates/) its a pretty straightforward process.

What specifically are you having issues with?